What is your goal when asking ChatGPT to assess the comments received in reply to your question?

Your recent question is one from a series of variations about
the theme of physicalism via anti-physicalism and the status of
mathematical theorems. You posted several related questions within a
short period of time and prompted extended discussions in the comment
section.

Your link here shows that subsequently you copied the comments and asked ChatGPT to assess the
comment section of our blog, notable the comments of other
participants.
Your subsequent step-by-step dialogue with ChatGPT raises the
question to which degree your posts and comments are triggered and shaped by
ChatGPT.

Hence I am wondering whether you are primarily interested in answers to the
philosophical problem under question. Or to which degree you use
us as guinea pigs to test the performance of ChatGPT?
Concerning questions where the latter is your goal: It would spare much effort of other participants,
when you restrict your Q&A-sessions exclusively to a
dialogue with ChatGPT.



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
